# Using cycle with tube for long distance

Tags: tire

I'm having Ralson 26*1.95 Tyre with tube....
I have heard that tubes burst due to friction at high speed.
Can I use it for travelling a distance of about 200 Km continuously and slowly??

Comment: *I have heard that tubes burst due to friction at high speed.*  That statement would provoke laughter from the vast majority of cyclists.  Tubes hardly ever burst unless the tire somehow fails.

Comment: If that tire is a knobby mountain bike tire, it will be slow on paved roads. You could ride 200km on it, but it would take a lot of effort. You could get a slick tire instead, if you're going on paved roads. Tubes do not burst due to friction, as Daniel said. You might want to ask the people who said this what the alternative is and why they think it's a better alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a tube will not overheat in those conditions.

Even riding very fast will not heat a bicycle inner tube. And even an under inflated bicycle tire will not warm appreciably.  An under inflated tire can fail or cause crashes but no it is not going to overheat as is the case with motorized vehicles.

Tandems descending 2+ mile steep (6% and greater) hills have been known to blow tires off of rims, but the tandems are 300+ pounds and the blown tires I'm aware of were all road tires 28mm or narrower AND the tandem had rim brakes. Tandems with disk brakes have no issues with overheating (blown) tires.

The larger the tire the more air volume so it takes more heat to warm the air and cause the tire to overheat.

The wider the rim the more heat will be dissipated. The air rushing against the rim & tire will cool the rim and tire.

A bicyclist simply doesn't have enough energy to appreciably warm a tire.

Comment: Concur - I've just checked - my 26" 1.75 tyres/tube/wheels have done 1,946.9km since Nov 26, 2019, at an average speed well above 30 km/h, with no burst tubes.  No punctures either.   So OP has pretty minimal risk of tube/tyre damage assuming inflation is correct and there are no sharps involved.

Comment: Blowing tires off rims on long down hills is largely due to the increased tire pressure from the heated air in the tube exceeding the tire or rim capability to contain the pressure.  https://www.sheldonbrown.com/brandt/blowouts.html. The reason larger tires are less prone to bursting is they tend to run lower pressures to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Please define slowly.

However, I guess it is physically possible, practically impossible.

- If you are pedaling, you cannot go *that* fast over 200 km distance.
- If you have an e-bike, the battery cannot last *that* long.

Comment: A heartly thanx to all of you